# Magento Site only works when ctrl + f5 is used

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

A Magento website is down in IE and in Firefox.  Magento provides the following message: "There has been an error processing your request. Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons."

However using Ctrl+F5 makes the site work.

The site works in Chrome and in Opera.

It also works if any page is requested other than the home page.

The error in the magento file in var/report lists:

a:4:{i:0;s:108:"SQLSTATE[HY000] [1203] User XXXXXXX   already has more than 'max_user_connections' active

However it still works in chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not a problem with Magento or the database.  The web host was incorrectly caching the site.  We found out when a file I uploaded still appeared in cPanel yet the file had been deleted several minutes before.

The web host flushed their cache of the site.  The website immediately loaded without any error.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your database; Basically your database is hitting the limit for the amount of connections for that user. Check what your max_user_connections setting is at and increase it.

Be careful, as the higher that number, the more resources it will use. You have to find an even balance.